# Code for jQuery Mobile selector menu?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I must be missing something obvious. I'm looking at the docs for jQuery Mobile, and nowhere do they give you the code to do the stuff they're demonstrating. I'm trying to create a selector menu... Where can I get the code for this (it must be like, one line, right)?

As a complete newbie, I'm at a loss here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you give a link to the page?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the code:

1. remove the # from the link: `jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html`
2. open in browser
3. view source (the old way, not with firebug or anything)

Comment: You're not the first. I'm doing jquery-mobile workshops and about half of the people had the same problem :)