# How to use jQuery Mobile selector menus?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've finally found the HTML for the jQuery Mobile selector menu component, thanks to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864538/code-for-jquery-mobile-selector-menu), but I'm stuck again.

I'm currently using this code, which works nicely:

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
        <label for="select-choice-nc" class="select">Font Choice:</label> 
        <select name="select-choice-4" id="select-choice-nc"> 

            <option value="arial">Arial</option> 
            <option value="papyrus">Papyrus</option> 
            <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option> 
            <option value="calibri">Calibri</option> 

        </select> 
    </div> 
</div><!-- /content -->
```

But how do I tell which option has been selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like jQuery sans Mobile (perhaps jQuery Immobile?). As with other form elements, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) to get the value of the `<select>`:

```
$('#select-choice-nc').val();
```

Comment: Oh, neat. :P Always nice to meet a fellow Rhode-Islander.